# the product of topological spaces is compact, then each of its factors is compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(X, T_1)$ and $(Y,T_2)$ be topological spaces. Prove that if $(X\times Y,T)$ is compact, then each $(X,T_1)$, $(Y,T_2)$ is compact.

Here is how I start this problem: Since $(X\times Y, T)$ is compact, each of its open covers has a finite subcover $O_{x_1}\times O_{y_1}$,...,$O_{x_n} \times O_{y_n} $

So, there is a finite number of $O_{x_1},...,O_{x_n}$. This is a finite subcover for X.
and there is a finite number of $O_{y_1},...O_{y_n}$. This is a finite subcover for Y

Therefore, $X$ and $Y$ are each compact. Please check my proof for me?
Thanks

Comment: The projections are continuous and so preserve compactness.

Comment: can you explain it more

Comment: @user110969 Do you know what he means by projection? Are you familiar with the fact that the continuous image of a compact set is compact?

Comment: It would be good to assume that the two spaces $X$ and $Y$ (also apparently known as $X1$ and $X2$) are nonempty. Without that assumption, the result is false.

Answer (score 5):

You’re off on the wrong foot altogether. If you’re going to work directly with open covers (instead of @lhf’s idea), you must start with an open cover of $X$ (or $Y$) and show that it has a finite subcover. Starting with an open cover of $X\times Y$ is pointless: you’re not trying to prove that $X\times Y$ is compact. (And note that open sets in $X\times Y$ do **not** necessarily have the form $U\times V$, where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$.)

Let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $X$. For each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ let $V_U=U\times Y$, and let $\mathscr{V}=\{V_U:U\in\mathscr{U}\}$. Show that $\mathscr{V}$ is an open cover of $X\times Y$ and apply compactness of $X\times Y$ to get a finite subcover of $\mathscr{V}$. Use this finite subcover to find a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ that covers $X$.

The proof that $Y$ is compact is entirely similar.

Comment: I was looking at this. http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/21S-Topology/Notes/Lec10.pdf Would part of this help

Comment: @HomerSimpson: Not really: it deals (among other things) with the converse of the desired result, i.e., that if $X$ and $Y$ are compact, then so is $X\times Y$. Here we know that $X\times Y$ is compact and want to show that $X$ and $Y$ are compact. The second paragraph of my answer leaves a few details to the reader but pretty much gives the proof.

Comment: Ok.would a subcover be {$x_0$} x Y $\subset$ X x Y  ,since the slice is homeomorphic to X xY ?

Comment: @HomerSimpson: No, you’ve no reason even to think that those sets are open. If $\mathscr{V}_0$ is a finite subcover of $\mathscr{V}$, all that you know about the members of $\mathscr{V}_0$ is that each of them has the form $U\times Y$ for some $U\in\mathscr{U}$. If $$\mathscr{V}_0=\{U_1\times Y,\ldots,U_n\times Y\}\,,$$ what can you say about $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$?

Comment: thought of using this theorem: Let X &Y be topo. spaces . Let X x Y have product topology. Then X and Y are each homeomorphic to a subspace of X x Y

{$U_1,…U_n$} they are open sub collection of sets? So have an open subcover?

According to Conover, this is the easier theorem ,lol

Comment: @HomerSimpson: If there is a point $x_0\in X$ such that $\{x_0\}$ is closed (e.g., if $X$ is $T_1$), then $\{x_0\}\time Y$ is a closed subset of $X\times Y$. A closed subset of a compact space is compact, so in that case we can conclude that $\{x_0\}\times Y$ is compact and hence that $Y$ is compact, since $\{x_0\}\times Y$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic. But if $X$ has no closed singletons, we can’t make this argument, because non-closed subsets of $X\times Y$ need not be compact. The argument that I sketched in my answer, however, still works in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Brian M Scott. So I will give alternate proofs.

Comment: @HomerSimpson: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 5):

*This answer expands on the brief comment of @lhf.*

---

This is a standard theorem in point-set topology (which I won't prove here unless you insist).

**Theorem:**  If $f:K \to L$ is a continuous map between topological spaces and $K$ is compact, then $L$ is compact as well.

And this is another standard proposition, where the product is given the product topology.

**Proposition:**  The projection maps $\pi_i: X_1 \times X_2 \to X_i$ for $i = 1, 2$ are continuous.

Putting these two results together, you get your claim as a direct corollary.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof should *start* with an arbitrary open cover of $X$ (or $Y$) and then show the existence of a finite subcover (by using the compactness of $X\times Y$).
Hint: If $U\subseteq X$ is open in $X$ then $U\times Y$ is open in $X\times Y$.